# Why should/should not I upgrade to react-native 0.60.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Currently, react-native has released version 0.60.0 and it has breaking changes but they have added many native supports in this version.

I am currently working on my 3 projects.

**First Project Info**
  - react: 16.0.0-beta.5 => 16.0.0-beta.5
  - react-native: 0.49.0 => 0.49.0
this project containes lots of third party libraries and some of them not event maintained by owners.

**Second Project Info**
  - react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3
  - react-native: 0.57.8 => 0.57.8
this project containes 12 third party libraries.

**Third Project Info**
  - react: 16.8.5 => 16.8.5
  - react-native: 0.59.2 => 0.59.2
this project containes 7 third party libraries.

Currently, all three projects are working in debug mode (Didn't try Release mode).
now I want to know from the above-mentioned project which one should I migrate to react-native 0.60.0 (Why)?
What if I don't migrate to react-native 0.60.0?
What are the challenges If I migrate to react-native 0.60.0?
Please guide me.
**Suggestions are Welcome.**

Comment: I can't do a full write-up right now but you can go through all the changes of each version here to see if there will be conflicts. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions

Answer (score 6):

Here is the specific version timeline that will benefit your app with the trade-off.

**v0.59.x**

- Android **64bit**, mandatory for play store publishing.
- React hooks
- new javascript core engine for android, make your app smoother.

**v0.60.x**

- CocoaPods by default, easier to integrate 3rd party library especially native module!
- AndroidX, this will break 3rd party library (even newer one and need time to update it).
- `Webview` and `Geolocation` is removed.
- Hermes javascript engine! **Faster startup**.

**Suggestions**

In my opinion, try upgrading to 0.59 is the safest sweet spot because without it, you can't publish your app on play store that requires your app 64 bit compatible. **0.60** can wait, as many of libraries (even newer one!) still not support **0.60**.

1. Obviously project with **0.49** is the hardest one to upgrade because sometimes you need to fork not-maintained-library and fix it by yourself.
2. Project with **0.57** will be much easier to upgrade to **0.59** because the structure mainly not changes a lot. You can refer to https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about react, but I've had to deal with a similar situation with android SDK, .net core, angular (JS), Xamarin, and Cordova, which I think allows me to make an educated guess, but, beware it a general approach.

So;

#### upgrading

**pros**

- in line with new features, big fixes, security fixes etc
- up to date with latest hardware
- small migration blocks (assuming you kept up with the update pase)

**cons**

- possible lose of hardware compatibility on older hardware
- need time for proper testing the exact behaviour (test automatisation helps)

#### not upgrading

**pros**

- saves time now
- keep compatibility with older hardware (for now)
- your current release is well tested, no surprises

**cons**

- will take more time to migrate in the future
- missing out on new features
- missing out on stability, security improvements etc.

#### pre release specific

In your case, since you are dealing with a pre 1.0 version?; you are a typical early adapter. This means you understand the risks involved and are aware of the high update frequency. I would therefore advise to update, but test it well.

... as a general approach ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Stefan 
That would be helpful to make a decision.